# Returning id with Prepared Statement

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I've created a registration page where everything works. Just wanna make this little insert return the id (which is set as auto increment). How would i go about doing so?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (street1, suburb, city, postcode, username) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

if (! $accres = $connection->prepare($sql)){
    $userinfo = "<font color = red>Account preparation failed: (" . $connection->errno . ") " . $connection->error . "</font>";
    showRegisterForm ( $userinfo );
} else {
    $accres->bind_param("sssss", $address, $suburb, $city, $postcode, $username);
    $accres->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read it from connection variable:

```
//execute query then:
$id = $connection->insert_id;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php